# Uploading video to an owned youtube channel

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to upload video using my developer key to a youtube channel that is owned by my google account.

```
$authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
$httpClient =
  Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
              $username = 'username',
              $password = 'pass',
              $service = 'youtube',
              $client = null,
              $source = 'mysource', // a short string identifying your application
              $loginToken = null,
              $loginCaptcha = null,
              $authenticationURL);


    $developerKey = 'key';
$applicationId = 'Video Upload';
$clientId = 'Video Uploader v1';
```

However when i try to upload to that channel it gives me "write-access" error even though this  channel is owned by me.
I can manage this youtube channel easily using "switch account" of youtube. but when it comes to upload using the API i get write-access error.

I use upload url like this

```
http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/CHANNELUSERNAME/uploads
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api.html) will give you the right information on how to manage multiple channels via API.